# How to temporary stick paper/card together so it can be removed later without tearing and too much residue

Tags: material-selection, adhesives, paper, technique-selection

I am making a display/collage and need to stick some art works to mounting card to then be displayed in a frame.

However, it is highly like I'll want to rearrange or reuse the works in a different display or arrangement. I need them to be stuck flush to the back card. Which once mounted will be be flush with the glass of the frame.

Tape, most glue and blue/white tact do not seem appropriate (the have a enough "3D" size to leave a shadow.

So far the only option I can really think of is getting one of those glue sticks (Pritt Stick in the UK) and apply it very sparingly.

Comment: Can you clarify the "leave a shadow" part? Tacky putty is thick. Some double-sided tape containing a plastic substrate can be in the thickness range of paper. But just an adhesive layer, like from a glue stick or dry adhesive applicator, doesn't add significant thickness. Even if you roughly doubled the paper thickness by using double-sided tape, the edge shadow from the thickness wouldn't change noticeably.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you don't want to see even the shadow from the paper thickness, you would need to use cutouts on a mat the thickness of the paper so the paper sits flush with the surface (and then hide the slit between the paper and the mat), or taper the edge of the paper or add tapered fill around the edge.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a "**repositionable glue**," "**restickable glue**," or other **temporary glue**, which are typically available as sticks, liquids, and sprays, depending on your need. They create a lightly tacky layer similar to what you'll find on the back of a Post-It Note, allowing your item to behave in the same manner--sticking where you want it to stick, while being removable.

While it does necessarily leave a "residue" on the surface to which it is applied, I've never seen any of the ones I've used leave any residue or damage on the other surface, as long as the directions on the product are followed properly. Typically, the glue will specify to wait a designated time to ensure it doesn't transfer between the two surfaces and functions properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the purpose of rubber cement.  You can easily peel the two pieces apart, then roll up the remaining cement and flick it away.

Comment: I did not know about this, good thing. To make the answer better, please add a link to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @virolino, I don't know whether there is a Wikipedia page on rubber cement or not.  It is so common that I would be surprised if there were, and I'm surprised you have never heard of it.  Do a web search for "rubber cement" and you will find more information than you can imagine...

Comment: how do you guess I found the Wikipedia page on rubber cement? :) Although I never used the rubber cement myself, I have seen it used several times - I just did not know it was named that way.

Comment: How?  By typing "rubber cement" I guess.  That's how most people find things on the internet.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use basic low tack masking tape for things like this. It comes off of most surfaces without leaving a mark. If you have a bigger budget try frog tape. Which is used for masking off areas when painting.

Comment: The question is about making a collage of artwork that will be displayed.  Are you suggesting covering part of the art and mounting board with masking tape? Besides the appearance, you're aware that even low tack masking tape could ruin the art when removing it, especially if it remains in place for a while?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if you put it on the back.

Comment: The question describes a concern about the thickness of whatever is used as an adhesive. A loop of masking tape will add more thickness than any other alternative with the possible exception of tacky putty.